# ReactJS class component render array.map using contenteditable elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, contenteditable

I'm having an interesting issue that I cannot debug.

**Goal**

On a class component, inside of render function, iterate over an array of objects from `state` using `this.state.items.map((item, index) => {})` and return a `contentEditable` paragraph element.

On each `contentEditable` paragraph element, listen for the `onKeyUp` event. If the key being used from `e.which` is the enter (13) key, add a new item to `this.state.items` using the index of the element that was keyed, in order to insert a new element after that index using `splice`.

**Seeing Expected Result?**

No. The newly added item is instead being put at the end of the loop when it is being rendered.

Example situation and steps to reproduce:

1. Type "test1" into the first `P` element
2. Hit enter (a new `P` element is created and focused)
3. Type "test2" into this second, newly created, `P` element
4. Refocus on the first `P` element, either by shift+tab or clicking
5. Hit enter
6. See observed results: a new `P` element is created and focused, but it is at the end of the list and not where it is intended to be, which is between the "test1" and "test2" `P` elements

---

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            items: [this.paragraphTemplate()]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <div>
                    {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
                        return <p ref={item.ref} 
                                  key={index}
                                  contentEditable 
                                  suppressContentEditableWarning 
                                  onKeyUp={e => this.handleParagraphKeyUp(e, index, item)}></p>
                    })}
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }

    handleParagraphKeyUp = (e, index, item) => {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            let addition = this.paragraphTemplate()

            this.setState(state => {
                state.items.splice(index + 1, 0, addition)

                return {
                    blocks: state.items
                }
            }, () => {
                addition.ref.current.focus()

                /* clear out the br and div elements that the browser might auto-add on "enter" from the element that was focused when the "enter" key was used */
                this.state.items[index].ref.current.innerHTML = this.state.items[index].ref.current.innerHTML.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '').replace(/<[\/]?div>/gi, '')
            })

            return false
        }
    }

    paragraphTemplate = () => {
        return {
            ref: React.createRef()
        }
    }
}

export default MyComponent
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptvjw348/1/) with the code from above.

If you take the above steps, you will see the issue that I am having.

Let me know if you require any further information, thanks in advance!

P.S. Please let me know if there any improvements that I can make to the code. I have been working in React for a short amount of time, and would love any feedback on how to make it better/cleaner.

**UPDATED**

Added `key={index}` to the `P` element. Note: this does not reflect any answers, it was merely added to stay in line with ReactJS list rendering.

Comment: You need to use a key on the `<p contentEditable >` and that `key` can not be the `index`, or the new item will be rendered at the end; again.

Comment: @Thomas Yes you are correct, I did forget to put in the `key` (it was in my code locally, but didn't make it into the fiddle). However; I did not know that you could not use `index`.  That's new to me thanks!  I'll update the question to include the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to render a list of items, React needs key to keep track of the element
see this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dq8Luawt/) that working..

```
<p ref={item.ref} 
   key={item.id}
   contentEditable 
   suppressContentEditableWarning 
   onKeyUp={e => this.handleParagraphKeyUp(e,
```

Comment: Thanks @Tubc! Going off of the comment from @Thomas and this, I now know something I didn't, and it's working as expected.

Comment: @klye_g one more note is I'm still using index as a key. but only when I know the list will never update the order, it's more convenience because we don't have real id always.